# Regex to find PHP variables in string

Tags: php, regex, sublimetext

I am trying to find all cases of PHP variables that are within strings.

All PHP variables begin with the $ character, so I am basically searching for that character within double quoted strings.

I want my regex to work for strings that are over multiple lines as well.
So far I have this:

```
"[^"]*?\$[\w\d]+[^"]*?"
```

However in say this case:

```
"a string" with no $variable in it

"a single line string with a $variable in it"
```

On the first line the last quote up to the end of $variables is matched. Obviously, if the regex should only search for this character within the quotes.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the example of `"" quotes contain $variables
` is matched ? http://regex101.com/r/wM7iK6

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior either (@Anoop be careful, you added a newline at the end of your regex)... How is your code called? On what actual string are you using it? Your regex doesn't account for escaped quotes, maybe a previous one broke the pattern?

Comment: @Robin, I checked after removing the newline as well. Does not seem to make a difference

Comment: I am using Sublime Text which uses the perl or boost syntax for regular expressions. I have since tested the regex in an online test environment like the regex101 site you used and there doesn't seem to be a problem with it, although it is still not working in Sublime Text. It may be a bug in Sublime Text's implementation of their regex engine. Thanks for your help though

Comment: Actually, here is an example of the error I am getting http://regex101.com/r/kH2nI6

Comment: @BenGuest: nope, not a bug. What do you want to do with these variables? Just select them, or more?

Comment: You can try with: `("[^"$]*")|("[^"]*?\$[^"]*")` and use the capture group number to find in which case you are. However, as I explain it in my answer, this is a very naive pattern that can't deal with the PHP syntax traps.

Comment: I just want to find cases where I am interpolating variables in strings. Its really just part of a list of regex's I use on my code before I deploy it to check for consistency etc. and to generally clean up my code. The link I provided above has the case that I am struggling with in it

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte, that is very close to what I want. Thank you! I just need to filter my results to contain only ones from the 2nd capture group. Re the naive pattern bit, that doesn't matter as I am using the regex for a global search so will be able to add some human common sense to the results.

Comment: @BenGuest: Yes but keep in mind that a single `'"'` in your code will break the pattern. It will be better to load your php file as a string in a php script that use the tokenizer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way to do that is to use the [tokenizer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php):

```
$source = <<<'EOD'
<?php // <-- needed
$data = 'Sed pulvinar metus $eget';
echo "tellus euismod tristique. $Nullam vitae";
if ($data === "mi id risus {$pretium['porttitor']} $vitae a lorem.")
// Aenean laoreet $urna eu erat laoreet, sit amet pretium purus consequat.
/* print "Curabitur $iaculis augue eget arcu dapibus"; */
echo <<<DATA
Duis id $mauris at ante ornare eleifend at sed magna
DATA;
EOD;

$tokens = token_get_all($source);
$flag = false;
$result = array();

foreach ($tokens as $token) {
    if ($token =='"')
        $flag = ! $flag;
    elseif ($flag && is_array($token) && $token[0] == T_VARIABLE)
        $result[] = $token[1]; 
}
print_r($result);
```

Indeed, it can be done too with a regex pattern. However, the pattern will be more complicated than you think, since you need to skip: comments, strings within simple quotes, heredoc, nowdoc, double quotes string without variable inside. To give you an idea, take a look at [this post](http://www.developpez.net/forums/d1431845/php/langage/regex/suppression-commentaire-php/) about php comments.

Note: You can easily change this code to handle heredoc syntax too (or whatever you want)

Answer (score 1):

**Why your regex is failing**

Consider what's happening when you apply `"[^"]*?\$[^"]*"` on the string

```
"a string" with no $variable in it "here's $foobar"
```

What you want to do is select `$foobar`. But the regex engine goes from left to right, so first it will try to match `"a string"` (`[^"]` prevents from going outside the quotes).

Not working, no problem, since the regex isn't anchored transmission kicks in and we try from the second quote: `" with no $variable in it "`. This matches, so is returned.

Since the match "ate" the third quote, we don't match `here's $foobar"`. You end up selecting `$variable` and not `$foobar`.

**Solving (naively) the issue**

To avoid this behavior, we need to match the quoted strings containing no variable as well. That way, only coherent "reel" string will be considered as potential matches by the regex.

You could use

```
("[^"]*?\$[\w\d]+[^"]*")|("[^"]*")
```

The quoted strings with variable would be captured in the first group, the others in the second; see [here for an example](http://regex101.com/r/cK7tK9).

**Disclaimer**

This is a quick solution and doesn't account for escaped quotes, comments, and everything Casimir et Hippolyte talked about in his answer (and usually, the right decision is to listen to him).

Depending of the scope of what you want to do it might still be suited, but to use it correctly you have to be aware of its limitations.

...and now I see that you've already discussed all of this in the comments, hope this post makes things clearer anyway :)